# unrecognised tag configuration in frontend-maven-plugin

Tags: maven

I use front-end-maven-plugin this way

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                </execution>
                <configuration>
                    <nodeVersion>8.11.3</nodeVersion>
                    <npmVersion>6.3.0</npmVersion>
                </configuration>                
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and I have this error

`[ERROR] Malformed POM /Users/admin/Application-Marwen/workspace/Tourism/Tourism-Web/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'configuration'`

Could you please help me. Thank you

Comment: The `<configuration>..</configuration>` part must be put into the `<execution>..</execution>` block...and not outside....

Comment: Hello khmarbaise and thank you for your answer. That's it